# Kubernetes Ingress Controller returning 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

So, I have an ingress controller routing traffic to three different services, but only one is working, all others are returning 503.
**INGRESS YAML**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /equip
        backend:
            serviceName: web-equip-svc-2
            servicePort: 18001
      - path: /hello
        backend:
            serviceName: hello-service
            servicePort: 80
      - path: /equip-ws
        backend:
            serviceName: web-equip-svc-2
            servicePort: 18000
```

**WORKING SVC YAML**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-service
  namespace: linkerd-test
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

**NOT WORKING SVC YAML**

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-equip-svc-2
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: equipment-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: equipment-service
  ports:
  - name: "http"
    port: 18001
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - name: "websocket"
    port: 18000
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
```

So, I've already tried to change annotations from ingress, change svc from clusterIP to loadBalancer... and nothing worked, any help would be welcomed

Comment: I think the question in this case would be: can you access web-equip-svc-2:18001 and web-equip-svc-2:18000 from other pods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should keep your services as ClusterIP if you can. The point of the Ingress Controller is to have one centralised ingress into your cluster.

**First thing to try**

Test your services independently first. (The two that are not working). Exec into another pod that is running, and do:

`curl http://web-equip-svc-2:18001` and see if you get a response back going directly to the service rather than via your ingress. If that works fine, then you know its a problem with your ingress rule configuration and/or controller.

If it doesn't work, then you know its just your actual container/pod that is running those two services, and you can focus there and fix the problem there first.

**Second thing to try**

Simplify your ingress rule. Remove the path for `/equip-ws` as a start, and have just your paths for `/hello` and for `/equip`.

```
      - path: /equip-ws
        backend:
            serviceName: web-equip-svc-2
            servicePort: 18000
```

Then test `http://localhost/hello` and `http://localhost/equip` again with the simplified ingress rule changed.

If this works then you know that your two equip paths in your ingress rule are causing issues and you can fix the conflict/issue there.

Comment: I'm able to use curl and get a valid response, but still no success with ingress. Already tried with just Hello and Equip. The problem persists

Comment: Did you try split your ingress rule that covers the three /paths into individual ingress rules (all with the same hostname of `localhost`, but with the different paths on each)? Can you also try running your test pods / services in the one namespace where your one working ingress service is running? It appears you're splitting your ingress rule, and services into multiple different namespaces. To rule out that as a potential issue, I'd recommend putting everything in one namespace to begin with to test.

Comment: Tried both ideas, all applications are running on the same namespace as the Ingress and did split the single rule into two rules. No success. :(

Comment: I've managed to get it to work. I did as you sugested and split the host, but instead of adding a path (localhost/hello) I added as part of the host, so hello.localhost. And it worked! For all three services, even the websocket one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10):

For me I had another ingress for the same host in another namespace (I forgot about
it)

```
kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces | grep <HOST>
```

helped me find it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution, 
As [@Shogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677577/shogan) suggested I split the rules on different hosts, but still no success, so instead of using Paths, I added prefixes to the host and it worked.

```yaml
rules:
  - host: hello.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /hello
        backend:
          serviceName: hello-service
          servicePort: 280
  - host: equip.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-equip-svc
          servicePort: 18001
  - host: ws.equip.localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-equip-svc
          servicePort: 18000
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to [@Shogan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57936832/3088045), another thing to verify is that the port specified by the *ingress* matches the port specified in the *service* configuration.

Not applying here, @Thiago's config, but in my case the HTTP 503 was returned because of *service* specifying a port named `http`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  ....
spec:
  selector:
    ....
  ports:
    - name: http  # here is the port name to refer inside the ingress
```

but the ingress specifying a port named `httpS` (this was a typo; I had no port named `https` into my service):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  ....
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: "localhost"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp-http
                port:
                  name: https    # here was the typo
```

This was breaking the routing from the ingress toward the correct port of the service.
Hence the [*503 HTTP status (Service Unavailable)*](https://www.webfx.com/web-development/glossary/http-status-codes/what-is-a-503-status-code/).

Although, IMHO, [an *HTTP 502 (Bad Gateway)](https://www.webfx.com/web-development/glossary/http-status-codes/what-is-a-502-status-code/)* would have been more clear on what's the cause of the issue, since the **service actually is available but just not reachable**.

Answer (score -1):

make sue you service and ingress is deployed on same namspace

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).